# JS function for button not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page that shows a table of records and in one of the columns I have a 'Print' button:

```
<td>
    <input type="button" class="btn-print" value="Print" id="printrec">
</td>
```

I have the javascript file added to the php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/logic.js"></script>
```

The function in logic.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Print selected record's entry form
    $('#printrec').click(function() {
        alert("Print btn pressed");
    });
});
```

Other buttons on the page work, calling the appropriate js function by ID, but nothing happens when I click 'Print'. Any ideas?

**Edit**
searchEntries.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Adobe GoLive" />
    <title>Contest Entry Search</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/logic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="entry-number" class="form-control" placeholder="Entry # (separate multiple entries with commas)" value="" name="con-year" />
<input type="button" id="formsearch" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
</form>
        <table id="show-entries">
        <tr class="tbhead">
            <th> Select </th>
            <th style="display:none"> ID </th>
            <th> Entry # </th>
            <th> Barcode </th>
            <th> Entrant Name </th>
            <th> Title of Entry </th>
            <th> Category </th>
            <th> Paid </th>
            <th> Date Paid </th>
            <th> Date Created </th>
            <th> Date Last Updated </th>
            <th> Last Updated By </th>
            <th> Print </th>
        </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**searchentries.php**

```
<?php
.
.
.
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // Loop through resultset and add to JSON object
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $json[] = $row;
        }
        // Return encoded JSON object to logic.js
        echo json_encode($json);
    } else {
        echo "NoResults";
    }
```

**logic.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var check="checklist";
    var unCheck ="unchecked-list";
    var cantCheck ="cantCheck";

    //select all button 
    $('#selectall').click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').prop('checked', true);
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').attr('class', 'checklist');   
        }
        else {
            //unchecked here
            $('#show-entries .checklist').prop('checked', false);
            $('#show-entries .checklist').attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    //checking checkbox
    $(document).on('change','.checklist, .unchecked-list',function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $(this).attr('class', 'checklist');
        }
        else {
             //unchecked here
             $(this).attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    $('#formsearch').click(function() {

        //getting values of text boxes
        var  contestYear= $('#contest-year').val();
        var  entryNumber= $('#entry-number').val();
        var  barCode= $('#barcode').val();
        var  firstName= $('#first-name').val();
        var  lastName= $('#last-name').val();
        var  title= $('#title-name').val();

        //remvoing previous row 
        $('.child').remove();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/searchreceive.php",
                data:{"c_year": contestYear, "e_number": entryNumber, "bCode":barCode, "fName":firstName, "lName": lastName, "title":title} 

        }).done(function(status) {
            status=status.trim();
            if(status=="NoResults") {
                alert("No records found - please try again.");
            }
            else {
                var result = JSON.parse(status);
                var p;
                var paidOp;

                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    // Loop through each record in 'status'

                    //getting date paid
                    var datePaid =result[i]["DatePaid"];
                    if(datePaid==null) {
                        datePaid = "";
                    }

                    //getting yes no for paid
                    p = result[i]["Paid"].trim();
                    if(p==1) {
                        paidOp="Yes";
                    }
                    else {
                        paidOp="";
                        //datePaid="";
                    }

                    //getting date created
                    var dateCreated =result[i]["DateCreated"];
                    if(dateCreated==null) {
                        dateCreated = ""; 
                    }

                    //getting date last updated
                    var dateUpdated =result[i]["DateLastUpdated"];
                    if(dateUpdated==null) {
                        dateUpdated = "";      
                    }

                    //getting last updated by
                    var updatedBy =result[i]["LastUpdatedBy"];
                    switch(updatedBy) {
                        case "wf_boxoffice":
                            updatedBy = "Box Office";
                            break;
                        case "wf_anon":
                            updatedBy = "Entrant";
                    }

                    $('#show-entries').append('<tr class="child"><td ><input type="checkbox" class='+unCheck+'  id='+result[i]["ID"]+'></td>\
                        <td style="display:none">'+result[i]["ID"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entry_Form_Number"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Barcode_Text"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entrant_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Model_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Category_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+paidOp+'</td>\
                        <td>'+datePaid+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateCreated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateUpdated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+updatedBy+'</td>\
                        <td><input type="button" class="btn-print"  value="Print" id="printrec"/></td>\n\
                    </tr>');

                    //checking paid or not  and disabling checkbox if FALSE
                    if(result[i]["Paid"]==1) {
                        //disabling unpaid checkboxes
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).prop('disabled', true);

                        //changing classs name of unchecked
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).attr('class', 'cantCheck');
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    });

    // Proceed button click
    $('#paid').click(function() {
        //getting ids of checkboxes
        var idArray = [];
        $('.checklist').each(function () {
            idArray.push(this.id);
        });

        if(idArray.length>0) {
            //call ajax for updating rows
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/updatepaid.php",
                    data:{idArray:idArray} 

            }).done(function(status) {
                status=status.trim();
                alert(status);
                window.location.href = '../index.php';
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("No row selected");
        }
    });

    // Reset all data
    $('#formreset').click(function() {
        //remvoing table rows 
        $('.child').remove();
    });

    // Print selected record's entry form
    $('#printrec').click(function() {
        alert("Print btn pressed");
    });
});
```

**Edit #2 - logic.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    addClickHandlers('.printrec');
    }, 1000);

    var check="checklist";
    var unCheck ="unchecked-list";
    var cantCheck ="cantCheck";

    //select all button 
    $('#selectall').click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').prop('checked', true);
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').attr('class', 'checklist');   
        }
        else {
            //unchecked here
            $('#show-entries .checklist').prop('checked', false);
            $('#show-entries .checklist').attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    //checking checkbox
    $(document).on('change','.checklist, .unchecked-list',function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $(this).attr('class', 'checklist');
        }
        else {
             //unchecked here
             $(this).attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    $('#formsearch').click(function() {

        //getting values of text boxes
        var  contestYear= $('#contest-year').val();
        var  entryNumber= $('#entry-number').val();
        var  barCode= $('#barcode').val();
        var  firstName= $('#first-name').val();
        var  lastName= $('#last-name').val();
        var  title= $('#title-name').val();

        //remvoing previous row 
        $('.child').remove();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/searchreceive.php",
                data:{"c_year": contestYear, "e_number": entryNumber, "bCode":barCode, "fName":firstName, "lName": lastName, "title":title} 

        }).done(function(status) {
            status=status.trim();
            if(status=="NoResults") {
                alert("No records found - please try again.");
            }
            else {
                var result = JSON.parse(status);
                var p;
                var paidOp;

                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    // Loop through each record in 'status'

                    //getting date paid
                    var datePaid =result[i]["DatePaid"];
                    if(datePaid==null) {
                        datePaid = "";
                    }

                    //getting yes no for paid
                    p = result[i]["Paid"].trim();
                    if(p==1) {
                        paidOp="Yes";
                    }
                    else {
                        paidOp="";
                        //datePaid="";
                    }

                    //getting date created
                    var dateCreated =result[i]["DateCreated"];
                    if(dateCreated==null) {
                        dateCreated = ""; 
                    }

                    //getting date last updated
                    var dateUpdated =result[i]["DateLastUpdated"];
                    if(dateUpdated==null) {
                        dateUpdated = "";      
                    }

                    //getting last updated by
                    var updatedBy =result[i]["LastUpdatedBy"];
                    switch(updatedBy) {
                        case "wf_boxoffice":
                            updatedBy = "Box Office";
                            break;
                        case "wf_anon":
                            updatedBy = "Entrant";
                    }

                    $('#show-entries').append('<tr class="child"><td ><input type="checkbox" class='+unCheck+'  id='+result[i]["ID"]+'></td>\
                        <td style="display:none">'+result[i]["ID"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entry_Form_Number"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Barcode_Text"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entrant_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Model_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Category_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+paidOp+'</td>\
                        <td>'+datePaid+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateCreated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateUpdated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+updatedBy+'</td>\
                        <td><input type="button" class="btn-print printrec" value="Print"/></td>\n\
                    </tr>');

                    //checking paid or not  and disabling checkbox if FALSE
                    if(result[i]["Paid"]==1) {
                        //disabling unpaid checkboxes
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).prop('disabled', true);

                        //changing classs name of unchecked
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).attr('class', 'cantCheck');
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    });

    // Proceed button click
    $('#paid').click(function() {
        //getting ids of checkboxes
        var idArray = [];
        $('.checklist').each(function () {
            idArray.push(this.id);
        });

        if(idArray.length>0) {
            //call ajax for updating rows
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/updatepaid.php",
                    data:{idArray:idArray} 

            }).done(function(status) {
                status=status.trim();
                alert(status);
                window.location.href = '../index.php';
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("No row selected");
        }
    });

    // Reset all data
    $('#formreset').click(function() {
        //remvoing table rows 
        $('.child').remove();
    });
});

function addClickHandlers(identifier) {
  $(identifier).click(function() {
    data = "";
    $(this).parents('tr').children().each(function() {
        data += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    alert("Print btn pressed from " + data);
  });
}
```

**Edit #3**
I only need the value from the first column in the table to pass to the php file, but as it's a hidden column I can't use .text() like this:

```
data = $(this).parents('tr').find("td:first").text();
```

Is there another way to get one column value only from a row, if it's hidden? The solution works fine for getting all column values, even the first hidden one, but it doesn't seem to work on its own.

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?  When you debug this, when assigning this click handler does `$('#printrec')` find the element at all?  This looks fine, but anything could be wrong that you're not showing us.

Comment: Are you repeating the same ID in page? Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: There is a print button for each row in the table, so maybe that's a problem. But even if I only have 1 record nothing happens on click. How do I check for errors on the console? I'm a newbie when it comes to JS debugging. I don't see any errors in my Apache log folder, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal attempt of what you might be trying to achieve:

Using PHP to generate the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#printrec').click(function() {
          alert("Print btn pressed");
      });
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
  echo '<table>'.
    '<tr>'.
      '<td>'.
        '<input type="button" class="btn-print" value="Print" id="printrec">'.
      '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
  '</table>';
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Using plain HTML to generate the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#printrec').click(function() {
          alert("Print btn pressed");
      });
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn-print" value="Print" id="printrec">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can you verify the code against the above snippet?

**Update 1: After OP posted more details in comments.**

If the HTML input is being added dynamically, then call the addClickHandlers() function with the ID of the HTML input you want to associate the click event to. Look at the below snippet for an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        addClickHandlers('#printrec');
      }, 3000);
    });
    function addClickHandlers(id) {
      $(id).click(function() {
          alert("Print btn pressed");
      });
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn-print" value="Print" id="printrec">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Update 2: After OP posted more details in comments and original post.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    addClickHandlers('.printrec');
    addClickHandlers('.printrec');
  }, 1000);
});
function addClickHandlers(identifier) {
  $(identifier).off("click");
  $(identifier).click(function() {
    data = "";
    $(this).parents('tr').children().each(function() {
        data += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    alert("Print btn pressed from " + data);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 1 Data 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 1 Data 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 1 Data 3
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn-print printrec" value="Print">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Row 2 Data 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 2 Data 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Row 2 Data 3
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn-print printrec" value="Print">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Update 3: Modified OP's logic.js.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var check="checklist";
    var unCheck ="unchecked-list";
    var cantCheck ="cantCheck";

    //select all button 
    $('#selectall').click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').prop('checked', true);
            $('#show-entries .unchecked-list').attr('class', 'checklist');   
        }
        else {
            //unchecked here
            $('#show-entries .checklist').prop('checked', false);
            $('#show-entries .checklist').attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    //checking checkbox
    $(document).on('change','.checklist, .unchecked-list',function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked here
            $(this).attr('class', 'checklist');
        }
        else {
             //unchecked here
             $(this).attr('class', 'unchecked-list');
        }
    });

    $('#formsearch').click(function() {

        //getting values of text boxes
        var  contestYear= $('#contest-year').val();
        var  entryNumber= $('#entry-number').val();
        var  barCode= $('#barcode').val();
        var  firstName= $('#first-name').val();
        var  lastName= $('#last-name').val();
        var  title= $('#title-name').val();

        //remvoing previous row 
        $('.child').remove();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/searchreceive.php",
                data:{"c_year": contestYear, "e_number": entryNumber, "bCode":barCode, "fName":firstName, "lName": lastName, "title":title} 

        }).done(function(status) {
            status=status.trim();
            if(status=="NoResults") {
                alert("No records found - please try again.");
            }
            else {
                var result = JSON.parse(status);
                var p;
                var paidOp;

                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    // Loop through each record in 'status'

                    //getting date paid
                    var datePaid =result[i]["DatePaid"];
                    if(datePaid==null) {
                        datePaid = "";
                    }

                    //getting yes no for paid
                    p = result[i]["Paid"].trim();
                    if(p==1) {
                        paidOp="Yes";
                    }
                    else {
                        paidOp="";
                        //datePaid="";
                    }

                    //getting date created
                    var dateCreated =result[i]["DateCreated"];
                    if(dateCreated==null) {
                        dateCreated = ""; 
                    }

                    //getting date last updated
                    var dateUpdated =result[i]["DateLastUpdated"];
                    if(dateUpdated==null) {
                        dateUpdated = "";      
                    }

                    //getting last updated by
                    var updatedBy =result[i]["LastUpdatedBy"];
                    switch(updatedBy) {
                        case "wf_boxoffice":
                            updatedBy = "Box Office";
                            break;
                        case "wf_anon":
                            updatedBy = "Entrant";
                    }

                    $('#show-entries').append('<tr class="child"><td ><input type="checkbox" class='+unCheck+'  id='+result[i]["ID"]+'></td>\
                        <td style="display:none">'+result[i]["ID"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entry_Form_Number"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Barcode_Text"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Entrant_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Model_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+result[i]["Category_Name"]+'</td>\
                        <td>'+paidOp+'</td>\
                        <td>'+datePaid+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateCreated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+dateUpdated+'</td>\
                        <td>'+updatedBy+'</td>\
                        <td><input type="button" class="btn-print printrec" value="Print"/></td>\n\
                    </tr>');

                    //checking paid or not  and disabling checkbox if FALSE
                    if(result[i]["Paid"]==1) {
                        //disabling unpaid checkboxes
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).prop('disabled', true);

                        //changing classs name of unchecked
                        $('#'+result[i]["ID"]).attr('class', 'cantCheck');
                    }
                }
                addClickHandlers('.printrec');
            }
        }); 
    });

    // Proceed button click
    $('#paid').click(function() {
        //getting ids of checkboxes
        var idArray = [];
        $('.checklist').each(function () {
            idArray.push(this.id);
        });

        if(idArray.length>0) {
            //call ajax for updating rows
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/updatepaid.php",
                    data:{idArray:idArray} 

            }).done(function(status) {
                status=status.trim();
                alert(status);
                window.location.href = '../index.php';
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("No row selected");
        }
    });

    // Reset all data
    $('#formreset').click(function() {
        //remvoing table rows 
        $('.child').remove();
    });
});

function addClickHandlers(identifier) {
  $(identifier).off("click");
  $(identifier).click(function() {
    data = "";
    $(this).parents('tr').children().each(function() {
        data += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    alert("Print btn pressed from " + data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why would you add the button inside PHP code? It should just be plain HTML

Comment: @PauloHgo: OP says that "I have a php page that shows a table of records". He never mentioned if he is generating the button using PHP, or adding it as a plain HTML. So I just illustrated a generic example, which can be easily modified to remove the PHP statement. I have updated the answer to include the plain HTML version too.

Comment: I have a search record php page with a form that has no action or method on it; there's a button with id='formsearch' that invokes a function on the js file $('#formsearch').click(function) which has Ajax code to receive the JSON array of search results. It then adds the records to a table on the main search page using $('#show-entries").append, which is where the button(s) with id='"printrec" is added.

Comment: @RossW: So, is the button being added dynamically after the ajax calls?

Comment: @user2582706 - I hope my edit answers your question, but I believe so, yes. I will try your code tomorrow. Does it matter that all the JS code is in a separate file, logic.js? In other words, can I add your code to the bottom of the file? And will your code work if there are multiple records in the table that each have a Print button, all with the same id='printrec'?

Comment: @RossW: A separate file for JS should be fine. But, print buttons with same ID will not work. ID's have to be unique, and hence they are called ID. :) You can rather use classes for that. I will update my solution in a bit.

Comment: @RossW: I have updated the solution to meet your needs. :) In the future, please try to follow the minimal, complete, and verifiable example policy.

Comment: Thank you @uautkarsh, but I still don't see the popup. I added the two JS parts to my logic.js file, and updated the HTML for the button to use the new class, but no luck. Bear in mind that the logic.js file builds the HTML table for the page after receiving the JSON query results, so all the changes you made go into the same file. I will edit my post and upload the whole .js file if that helps.

Comment: @uautkarsh: Genius! I can't thank you enough - your assistance and patience with me is most appreciated.

Comment: @uautkarsh: if I only wanted the first column value (I'm going to pass that to a php file), how would the JS change? The column in question is 'id'

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work; data is blank: data = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();

Comment: @RossW: No problem. All I'll say is that make sure that you understand why the code is working as it is. Use this for the first coulmn -> $(this).parents('tr').children().first().html()